# Python 3 array, inverting polygon points

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates, points

I have a list of coordinates but the x,y coordinates are not in a tuple:

```
width,height = 100
#my_list = (x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
#my_list = (0, 50, 50, 0, 50, 100)
my_list = (0, height/2, width/2, 0, width/2, height)
```

These points can create a polygon shape. In my case a triangle filling half of the 100x100 area pointing to the left.

I am trying to invert (**horizontally**) the triangle so it would be pointing to the right so a solution would be:

```
my_list = (width, height/2, width/2, 0, width/2, height)
```

But I was thinking how should I make a function that would be able to invert horizontally any polygon? So something like this:

```
my_list = (0, height/2, width/2, 0, width/2, height)
invert_horizontally(my_list, width, height)
>>> (100, 50, 50, 0, 50, 100)
```

I think, that to invert the points, I have to do something like this:

```
for point in my_list:
    if this point is x:
        new_x = width - point
    else:
        pass
```

Well here is my issue: How to determine that the point is X. Also how to create a one-liner out of this code?

**Edit:**

My code so far:

```
new_list = [ @@@-point for point in my_list ]
```

the now the `@@@` would have to change depending on whether the point is x or y.

**Edit #2:**

Basically I need that **for every even item 'point' do width-point**

Comment: From the example you provided, the only difference I see is the first element which is initially `0` and later becomes `width`. Rest of the list remains the same. In that case, just do `my_list[0]= width` and return.

Comment: @Bazingaa that's because I used a square (symmetrical) 100x100 canvas. I wanted to create a one-liner that can be applied to any other polygon (mainly the non-symmetrical one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the points are stored sequentially as `x, y` values inside the list. Thus, you know that all the `x`'s are in even positions. A one liner might be:

```
inverted_triangle = [width-coord if i % 2 == 0 else coord for i, coord in enumerate(triangle)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iterator from `my_list`, `zip` with with itself to pair the x and y coordinates, and use the respective calculations for x and y to obtain the inverted coordinates:

```
def invert_horizontally(my_list, width, height):
    i = iter(my_list)
    return [coord for x, y in zip(i, i) for coord in (width - x, y)]
```

so that given your sample input,

```
invert_horizontally(my_list, width, height)
```

returns:

```
[100, 50, 50, 0, 50, 100]
```